# Windows Server 2008 NLB with VPS

Tags: windows-server-2008, nlb, arr

When using network load balancing should I use a public or private IP for the node addresses? The two nodes I will be clustering have both.  I have a third public IP that will be the shared IP to the internet - which the NLB cluster should receive then pass it to one of the nodes and then the ARR machine will then pass it off to one of the web/content servers.  A second question would be can I use private IPs for the nodes and then attach a public IP for the cluster IP?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an private IP to your NLB cluster, each node will be the private IP of your Webserver.

You will use NAT in your firewall to hook your public IP adresse to your Private IP adresse of your NLB.

Example

NLB cluster have the IP : 192.168.0.1

First cluster node will be : 192.168.0.2
Second cluster node will be : 192.168.0.3

To reach your server your IP adresse X.x.x.x will NAT to 192.168.0.1

I hope it's enougth clear ...